# Using LowProfileImageLoader programmicatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm attempting to follow the usage instructions for using the LowProfileImageLoader
on David Anson's blog to download remote images on a background thread here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx

The problem I have is that rather than use at design-time in xaml, I want to use it in code-behind. I can get a reference to the Delay namespace, but have no idea how to do the equivalent of

```
<Image
    delay:LowProfileImageLoader.UriSource="{Binding ProfileImageUrl}"
    Width="24"
    Height="24"/>
```

in C#.

All help welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The `LowProfileImageLoader` is a attached behaviour, with a attached property called `UriSourceProperty`.

So you simply bind the value of the attach property, like you would do with any other property, using `SetBinding`.

```
Image img = new BitmapImage();
img.SetBinding(Delay.LowProfileImageLoader.UriSourceProperty, new Binding("ProfileImageUrl"));
img.Width = 24;
img.Height = 24;
```